# How do I move image over a title header that is filled with a solid background color in power point?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to post an image over a solid filled title header in the master slide layout in power point.

Comment: right click -> move forward or similar

Answer (score 1):

Try to move it [forward](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/powerpoint2013/19.2) in the layers...

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work unofrtunately

Comment: @Maggie try to move the header BACKWARD

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work either

Comment: @Maggie I suggest you go MASTER editor and if you are in it  - place a screenshot of it